# htaccess LDAP auth with both username and email

Tags: authentication, .htaccess, ldap

I need an htaccess file that will allow a user to enter either the username or email address and still be logged in. I can make it work with one or the other but not both.
any ideas?
thanks in advance

Pete

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Log in"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPCompareAsUser on
AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser on
# AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern (.+) $1@school.edu
<If "%{REMOTE_USER} == %{REMOTE_USER}@school.edu">
    AuthLDAPURL ldaps://ad.school.edu:636/OU=Users,DC=school,DC=edu?mail
</If>
<Else>
    AuthLDAPURL ldaps://ad.school.edu:636/OU=Users,DC=school,DC=edu?sAMAccountName
</Else>
<RequireAll>
    require valid-user
</RequireAll>
```